# 代えさせていただきます sentence translation

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate this sentence

> 当選者の発表は、商品の発送をもって代えさせていただきます。

I know that をもって here means something like で

But I really can't understand the meaning of it and also what are some possible contexts.

Please help translate.

Comment: Aをもって(Bに)代える is a stiff and formal expression meaning "to use A as a substitute for B." For example 沈黙をもって同意に代える ("to regard silence as consent.")

Comment: Wouldn't "沈黙をもって同意に代える" mean "show/give one's consent through silence" rather than "regard silence as consent"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「当選者{とうせんしゃ}の発表{はっぴょう}は、商品{しょうひん}の発送{はっそう}をもって代{か}えさせていただきます。」

This is an extremely famous sentence used in prize contests and sweepstakes.

「代える」 here means "to substitute".

The sentence talks about taking the liberty of substituting the actual shipping of the prizes for the public announcements of the winners.  That is the literal meaning of it.

A more natural TL woud be:

> "Only winners will be notified."